# Get Multiple return values from .net webservice using SOAP and PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am calling a webservice written in .net through my PHP code.
The function in .net webservice has a return statement and an out parameter. I am able to get the value of the return variable but not the out parameter. Is there any way so that I can get both the return value and the out parameter of the function in webservice?

How can I get the `vFileID` from the following webservice through soapCall in PHP?
PHP Code

```
$client = new SoapClient("abc.wsdl");
$result = $client->__soapCall("SendFile", $params);
```

Output:

```
object(OIntegrate_Response)[301]
  public 'version' => null
  public 'schemaVersion' => null
  public 'schemaDocumentation' => null
  public 'contentType' => null
  public 'cacheControl' => null
  public 'data' => string '8129ac11-ab01-4abd-bbd8-1af79dbe1019' (length=36)
  private 'errors' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Here is the .net code:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public string SendFile(string vFileName, string vDescription, bool vLastChunk, bool vFirstChunk, Int32 vStartByte, byte[] vBytes, string vFileID, string vFile, out Int32 vID)
        {
            avFileTransferManager tmpFileManager;
            avFileManager tmpManager = new avFileManager();
            vID = 0;
            if (vFirstChunk)
            {
                vFileID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                tmpFileManager = new avFileTransferManager();
            }
            else
            {
                tmpFileManager = GetFileManager(vFileID);
            }

            tmpFileManager.AddChunk(vStartByte, vBytes);

            if (vLastChunk)
            {
                //Store file in database.
                avFile tmpFile = tmpManager.DeserializeFile(vFile);
                tmpFile.LockSize = false;
                tmpFile.FileStream = tmpFileManager.FileStream;
                //tmpFile.Name = vFileName;
                //tmpFile.Description = vDescription;                


                tmpFile = tmpManager.SaveFile(tmpFile);
                vID = tmpFile.ID;

                //Remove tmp-file from memory.
                Session.Remove(vFileID);
            }
            else
                Session[vFileID] = tmpFileManager;  //Store tmp-file in session object.

            return vFileID;
        }
```

Comment: Please post your code, so we can take a look at what you're doing.

Comment: We'll need the PHP-source as well. If the .net-code truly returns values (I have no experience with this language), the problem is in the PHP-file.

Comment: @OptimusCrime PHP code and output added.

Comment: could you also post the return values of $client->__getLastRequest(); and __getLastResponse();

Comment: How does a web service gain the value of an out param?  Sounds like a .net convention, but it must be represented in the wsdl somewhere.  I imagine your answer is in there also.  Can you sniff the response from your web service?  A hack would be to return both values from the web services standard return, seperate them with something ^^ and split the return on the php side.

Comment: In the above, "a web service gain" should read "a web service client gain"